# How to rescale several images to same size

Tags: scripting, images, imagemagick

I have several image files in a directory. These images are similar size and have same background color.

How can I make all images same size by adding background like this attached image?

[image]

Comment: This is possible (hint: see `-border` under "Image Operators" in `man convert`).  However, you do need a short program to do this and I won't write it in shell, so *if you are willing to accept* an answer in perl using `Image::Magick`, I can provide one.

Comment: do you know the largest dimensions beforehand?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' you don't really need a script.

Comment: @terdon That's a ridiculously absurd "one liner" if you need to *first* iterate all the images to find the largest geometry.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' true, but I'm assuming that only needs to be done once, or that the OP will know the size before hand.

Comment: @terdon $0.02: Presuming the size is not arbitrary ("known" before hand), which the diagram in the question strongly implies it isn't, it'd still be a dunderheaded way to go -- first iterate extracting geometry then iterate applying conversion.  You are not going to save yourself any effort vs. putting it in a script.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' depends on your scripting knowledge. I agree that I would probably do this with a script, but the devil's in the details. Dammit, now I'm going to have to go and script it! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work with all the image types that ImageMagick can handle without having to specify `*.png`, `*.jpg`, `*.jpeg` etc:

```
#!/bin/bash

images=$(identify -format '%f\n' * 2>/dev/null)

IFS=$'\n'
set -e

max_dims=$(
  identify -format '%w %h\n' $images 2>/dev/null |
  awk '($1>w){w=$1} ($2>h){h=$2} END{print w"x"h}'
  )

orig_dir=originals_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T)
mkdir "$orig_dir"
mv -- $images "$orig_dir"
cd "$orig_dir"

set +e

for image in $images; do
  convert -- "$image" -gravity Center -extent "$max_dims" "../$image"
done
```

This will move the original images into a dated directory in case the results are not desirable. Also, this will fail if, for whatever reason, the image files have newlines in their names.

This script could do with some more error messages to give a helpful indication if anything went wrong. But for now if there is any error moving the images (everything between the `set -e` and `set +e`), the script will exit. Hopefully this will avoid doing any irreversible damage.

#### Update

Now with `awk` script shamelessly plagiarised from [@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122592/48083).

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for "shameless" but I'd already upvoted you before (and it was your suggestion in the first place anyway) :)

Answer (score 6):

I took the opportunity to improve my bash skills and came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxx=0
maxy=0

# find largest dimension
for file in *.jpg ; do
  dim=$(identify "$file" | awk '{ print $3 }')
  xdim=$(echo $dim | cut -f1 -dx)
  ydim=$(echo $dim | cut -f2 -dx)
  if [ $xdim -gt $maxx ] ; then
    maxx=$xdim
  fi
  if [ $ydim -gt $maxy ] ; then
    maxy=$ydim
  fi
done

mkdir bordered

# resize and store new images in new folder
for file in *.jpg ; do
  dim=$(identify "$file" | awk '{ print $3 }')
  xdim=$(echo $dim | cut -f1 -dx)
  ydim=$(echo $dim | cut -f2 -dx)

  xborder=$(( ($maxx - $xdim ) / 2 ))
  yborder=$(( ($maxy - $ydim ) / 2 ))

  convert "$file" -bordercolor black -border ${xborder}x${yborder} "bordered/$file"

done
```

This should do the trick: it first loops over all files (change according to your needs) to find the largest width and height and then loops again to add the required borders (change the `-bordercolor black` part to suit your needs). The new files are stored in the "bordered" folder.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you select a target size that is larger than your largest image, you should be fine with the following:

```
mogrify -gravity Center -extent 200x200 -background white -colorspace RGB *png
```

The command above **will change the original file**, you might want to backup before running it. It uses `mogrify` from ImageMagick to resize all pngs in the current directory to 200x200px (`-extent 200x200`) by adding a white background (`-background black`) and centering the image (`-gravity Center`). The `-colorspace RGB` is needed to avoid errors like

```
mogrify.im6: Ignoring incorrect gAMA value when sRGB is also present `emacs-48x48.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1754.
```

To make sure you don't loose any image data, ensure that the size you use is larger or as large as the largest image you have. To get that quickly, try:

```
file *png | awk -F, '{print $2}' | sort -nu
```

That should print the sizes of all images sorted and you can easily find the largest.

---

To appease goldilocks (:P), you can automate the whole process:

```
dimensions=$(file *png | cut -d, -f 2 | sort -u | 
            awk '($1>w){w=$1}($3>h){h=$3}END{print w"x"h}') && 
mogrify -gravity Center -extent $dimensions -background white -colorspace RGB *png;
```

Comment: TIL the "file" command, nice! But does this line work to find out the largest width and heigth easily? Perhaps you should sort x and y size separately.

Comment: @Jasper indeed, that's just a hack, quick'n dirty®.

Comment: +1 For at least providing some basic steps ;) @Jasper you got my vote too, BTW.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I bowed before the altar of efficiency, see edit. Still no script :P.

Comment: Using `-resize` didn't work for me, I used `-extent` instead. Also if I used `-background` it had to come before the `-extent` (although it should default to white as per the Q).

Comment: @Graeme strange, it works as posted on my Debian and `mogrify` from `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10`. Did you maybe use `convert` instead of `mogrify`?

Comment: Tried both, maybe a difference in the test images. Also `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10`.

Comment: I tested I with a random image I downloaded from an ad on here - http://cdn.sstatic.net/unicoin/unicoin-sidebar.png?v=f21b4ef6fbd9

Comment: @Graeme huh, yes that one failed for me too. I edited to use `-extent` instead, thanks.

Comment: Do you still need `-colorspace` option with `-extent`? Also, you could do just do `print w"x"h` with `awk` then you can drop the `while` loop.

Comment: @Graeme you're absolutely right of course, thanks edited. And yes, I still get errors without the `-colorspace`, I think it depends on the image.

Comment: This is a cool hack the way you get max size, but it works only `png` image, `gif` has another order with `file` and `jpg` doesn't have size info with `file`. That's why I accepted @Jasper's as a best answer. Even though, I'm very grateful your help!

Comment: @Tetsu no worries, yes, `file` is just a hack, identify will be better but you can adapt this to use it instead.

Comment: @terdon It's a script by any other name -- or at least, a function sourced into the shell. Are you really going to "remember" and type that out every time you want to do it, or are you going to save it in a file?  If not, where's the efficiency?  You've sacrificed yourself on the altar of *pseudo-cleverness*. :P

Comment: @terdon, your `awk` script has ended up somewhere else on this thread. Don't know who would do such a thing... Btw you still need to shift the position of the `-background` (and possibly `-colorspace` too).

Comment: @Tetsu, my answer should work with all the image types that ImageMagick can handle.